# Manipulate reevaluate every time

Tags: manipulate, evaluation, dataset

my code is working, however I have a problem, every time I navigate to the pages of the dataset, the Manipulate performs a re-evaluation bringing me back to the first page of the dataset. I would like this not to be done. How can I stop the revaluation of Manipulate? I'm using Entity Dataset. This is my code:

```
Manipulate[
 Grid[{{
    AnatomyPlot3D[{AnatomyStyling[<|
        Entity["AnatomicalStructure", Parts] -> Color|>], 
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", entityName]}, ImageSize -> Medium,
      PlotTheme -> "Transparent"]},
   {Dataset[
     DeleteCases[
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", Parts]["Dataset"], _Missing], 
     HeaderBackground -> LightBrown, 
     Background -> {{{LightBlue, White}}}, MaxItems -> 9]}}],
 {Parts, list},
 {Color, colors},
 ContentSize -> {2500, 800},
 ]
```

Comment: With the setting `ContinuousAction->None`, an explicit Update button is displayed, and expr is not reevaluated until this is clicked. Would that help?

Comment: Your code is incomplete. `Manipulate` is subtle. Usually the problem has to be diagnosed, which needs a live patient.

Comment: @rhermans it didn't work, ```Manipulate``` reevaluated before the the button is clicked. I have noticed that if I abort the evaluation the ```Manipulate``` doesn't reevaluate.